# Minimization of product function subject to constraints

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

I want to minimize the following function:

$\prod_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}$

Subject to the following constraints:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{x_i}=1.1+(n-1)(0.1)$ and 
$0.1 \leq x_i \leq 1.1$

How should I go about it? I am trying to check if the minimum value is achieved when one of the $x_i$'s is 1.1 and everyone else is 0.1.

Comment: Well in your case, one of the $x_i$ should be $1.2$ to make that sum work out. You should try perturbing your situation, i.e. $x_i=1.2-\varepsilon$ and $x_j=0.1+\varepsilon_j$ (for $\sum\varepsilon_j=\varepsilon$) to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Now I fixed the typo.

Comment: I think it may be sufficient to assume $x_1=1.2$ and make the perturbation $x_2=0.1+\varepsilon$ and $x_1=1.2-\varepsilon$ to check the rate of change in each of the $x_i$ for $i\neq 1$.

Comment: let $y=\ln (\Pi_{i=1}^n x_i)$, then since $y=\ln x$ is concave, the maximum is achieve where each $x_i$ takes the same value.

Comment: @athos: I am trying to find the minimum value, not the maximum value.

Comment: By the same reasoning, you should find the minimum at one of the extremes of the domain then, as you've described.